# AngularJS promise resolution not updating GUI until next user interaction

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using an Angular2-style component in AngularJS.  In my component, I have a function that is meant to update the GUI by changing the options of a dropdown:

```
    var ctrl = this;
    async function updateOptions(node) {
          var name = node.name;
          let result = await MyService.getResult(name);
          ctrl.options = result;
          console.log(ctrl.options); 
    }
```

The corresponding HTML to display those options is:

```
  <select ng-if="$ctrl.getType() === 'dropdown'"
    class="form-control selectList"
    ng-model="$ctrl.value"
    ng-options="option.key as option.displayName for option in $ctrl.options">
  </select>
```

where `getType()` always returns `'dropdown'`.

The dropdown starts blank.  The user selects an option from the dropdown.  The console logs the options and the dropdown updates correctly.  The user selects ANOTHER option from the dropdown.  The console logs the options correctly AGAIN.  But THIS time, the dropdown does NOT update.  All subsequent times, the dropdown shows the options of the PREVIOUS thing the user selected.

Looking forward to some good detective work.  Happy to provide more snippets of code from this large project.  I'm wondering if this could be an issue with the way that AngularJS updates.

UPDATE:

MyService code:

```
this.getResult = function(name) {
  return myFactory.getStuff(name).then(
    function(response) {
      return response.result.map(...);
    }
  );
};
```

MyFactory code:

```
myFactory.getStuff = function(name) {
  return $http.get('/url/here/' + name)).then(
      function(response) {
        return response.data;
      }
    );
};
```

Comment: AngularJS used promises from the `$q` service which would run a digest for you. If you are using native promises, I think you need to run a digest manually.

Comment: @FrankModica Would it help to post code for the `getResult` method?  Unfortunately I am not familiar with the $q service, but I'll read up on it now.

Comment: In AngularJS usually people get API results using the built in`$http` service, which I believe returns promises which are created from the `$q` service. Thus a digest cycle is automatically run for you when the AJAX response is received. How is `getResult` implemented? Is it returning a native promise?

Comment: Using `.then` syntax instead of `await` seems to be working.  But for the sake of completeness, I have still included requested details above.  Perhaps you can post a brief answer below explaining why this works.  Thanks kindly for your help.

Comment: To be honest, I'm surprised it worked even once before. `await` should work on native promises, but not the ones from `$q`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await` is meant for native promises which are supported by the browser. You can also use `.then` syntax on native promises.

But AngularJS uses its own promises that come from `$q` service. Thus you are required to use `.then` syntax because the browser doesn't know about these promises.

When you use promises from the `$q` service (e.g. when you use `$http`) you don't have to worry about digest cycles because a digest is run for you when the promise is fulfilled. But if you use native promises in AngularJS, you usually have to run a digest cycle manually.

Comment: The term "digest" does not appear in the AngularJS documentation of `$q`.  Perhaps you could provide a link to a good resource that explains how/when angular "digests".

Comment: The digest cycle is a fundamental concept in AngularJS (it's how the framework accomplishes change detection). AngularJS has been out for so long that a google search would get you a ton of quality explanations. Once you understand the digest cycle, you really just need to know that `$q` triggers the digest cycle for you when you use its promises.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a way to manually run a digest cycle when using Angular2-style components in AngularJS.  `$apply` and `$digest`, for example, are not available.  I was able to get certain things to update properly by putting update code within a `this.$doChange` function where `this` is the controller.

Comment: On what object did you try to call `$digest`? You probably need to inject `$scope`